# angularjs: is it possible to access directive name from self directive compile function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to access directive name from self directive compile function?
Just to explain better what I mean:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      if (!attr.mandatoryParameter) return err(element, 'mandatory parameter not specified!');
      element.replaceWith('... ok ...');
    }
  };

  function err(el, reason) {
    el.replaceWith(I_WOULD_LIKE_TO_PRINT_MY_DIRECTIVE_HERE__ + ': ' + reason);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why an't you just hardcode it?

Comment: I don't like repeating code... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
compile: function(element, attrs) {
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could store it in a variable, in which case I would put it in a closure so it's not in the global namespace:

```
(function() {
  directiveName = 'myDirective';

  app.directive(directiveName, function() {
    // ...

    function err(el, reason) {
      el.replaceWith(directiveName + ': ' + reason);
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Right, but not so 'elegant'... :-)